# document.getElementById with a loop and local vs global var

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Need some help, whenever i try to use

```
document.getElementById( "writer" ).innerHTML = "Names: " + child123[i] + "<br>";
```

to replace

```
document.write(child123[i] + "<br>");
```

in my loop, it does not work. Not sure why, i believe i'm messing up the names and `<br>` but it still doesn't print when its just `child123[i];`

Also within my code, is there a better way to do my `merger()` and `sorter()` to where I don't have to concat the var's in sorter. I guess i need to know how to access `child123` from the `merger()` to use in there `sorter()`. I understand that i can't just do

```
function merger(){ 
var child12 = name1.concat( name2 ); 
var child123 = child12.concat( name3 ); 
document.getElementById( "writer" ).innerHTML = child123; 
} 

function sorter(){ 
child123.sort(); 
child123.reverse(); 
document.getElementById( "writer" ).innerHTML = child123; 
}
```

because of the global vs local. But there has go to be a better way of doing it as far as using the merger in my sorter.

I need to have the buttons do the merging and sorting and printing separate, as thats what my assignment says to do. I also have to use getElementbyId to write the sorted list to the page, with a name header.

Any help/explanations would be appreciated.

All the code:
http://pastebin.com/BB6ecU5D

Fiddle, not sure how to use it

https://jsfiddle.net/armadadamra/om1zh5bL/

Comment: as far I understand you need to concattinate string first and only than place it to innerHTML, or (not recomended) use `... ).innerHTML += ...`

Comment: js files  
js 1
http://pastebin.com/WEhmPkY4

js 2
http://pastebin.com/x2Psa5HY

js 3
http://pastebin.com/DSB0GhD8

Comment: create fiddle, at jsfiddle or plnkr

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/armadadamra/om1zh5bL/

Answer (score 0):

replace your loop with

```
document.getElementById( "writer" ).innerHTML = child123.join('<br>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/om1zh5bL/2/